# What does "no longer cease to exist" means?

Tags: american-english, british-english

I understand what "cease to exist" means, but **"something" no longer cease to exist** doesn't make sense to me. English is not my first language(obviosly).

Comment: How much a fan are you of historical revisionism?

Comment: @user867 This would also be a very useful construction in a world with time travel.

Answer (score 5):

The only way this makes sense to me is for describing something that for a while indeed had ceased to exist, but someone starting providing again.

The best example I can think of is the Twinkie, which for a while was unavailable due to the company owning the trademark going out of business. The trademark was sold, and the new owners started making Twinkies again. So for a while the Twinkie had "ceased to exist", but no longer.

Answer (score 0):

Something that is made available, which previously wasn't.

Comment: A thing that previously wasn't available often is a thing that never existed before, rather than something that previously ceased existence

Comment: @jwpat7 I think it's debatable. Taking the case of *justice* for insistence. Not available during dictatorship, doesn't mean that it never existed. But since you used *often* rather than  *always* therefore I would cautiously agree.

Comment: Something that is made available _again_ that previously had stopped being available.

Answer (score -2):

No longer (Stop)
Cease (Stop)
To (for the purpose of)
Exist (Be)

Stop Stop Being (who you are)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Stack Exchange answers are expected to strive to be THE answer to the question. This one, I'm afraid, doesn't even make sense. It's the responsibility of the answer to make sense of nonsense.